# How to bypass "Nock" for certain calls?

Tags: node.js, nock

I have setup my system such that every call I make can be intercepted by nock:

```
nock('example.com')
.get(/goodbye/)
.reply(200, {}, {})
```

Now every call I make is intercepted by nock and it returns the response. I am trying to setup nock such that sometimes I can bypass nock and make a call to the actual target server and get default responses from that server. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always filter your request by eg. [post body](https://github.com/nock/nock#specifying-request-body), or [headers](https://github.com/nock/nock#specifying-headers)
You can also use nock only for the first matched request or use [persist()](https://github.com/nock/nock#persist) fn so the interceptor will be applied to all matched requests.

So it depends on how you want to differentiate between calls which should be intercepted. If you want to just send the same requests and catch only for example every second, I would turn on persistence and then use [restore](https://github.com/nock/nock#restoring) and [activate](https://github.com/nock/nock#activating) functions for turning interceptor on and off.

Hope this helped.. check the documentation, it has pretty much all you need.

Comment: How can I talk to a target server by bypassing nock entirely ? and I appreciate the help! Thank You

Comment: You can pause nock from intercepting your calls.. or removing your mock completely. What is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Set `allowUnmocked: true` option, then all other unmocked requests goes to the actual server.

https://github.com/nock/nock#allow-unmocked-requests-on-a-mocked-hostname